# How do I move Navigation on @media query?

Tags: css

I have my navigation off to the left for desktop viewing.  I think I want to move it to the top of the screen for small devices...

right now it looks like:

```
LO
GO
__
__
__
```

I would like it to look like this when viewed on a small browser:

```
LO -- --
GO -- --
```

Normal viewing CSS is:

```
#nav {
width: 130px;
padding: 10px 10px 150px;
}

.nav-links {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
}
```

I attempted:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #nav {
    width: 25ems;
    height: 7ems;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;   
 }

  .nav-link a, .nav-link span.link-placeholder {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 30px; 
    top: 0;
}
```

But it won't budge... anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I feel like the way you want it to look should be reversed...

Answer (score 0):

I fumbled enough to stumble upon the answer.  I simply had to include a float:left; addition and suddenly everything lined up.

I also put width to 40% to give room for links and the logo.  here is the final CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #nav {
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;  
    top: 0;   
 }

.nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 147px;
}

.nav-link {
    display:inline;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    float:left; 
    width:40%;
    height:auto;
    font-size: 8.85px;   
}
```